# rails 4 undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass - category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to display an image according to a category name. My images are in the `app/assets/images`
My tutos will have categories that I have created in the console.
Now, I have this error (again...) `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`.
Thanks again for your precious help !

here is my form:

```
= simple_form_for @tuto do |f|
  - if @tuto.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      h2 = "#{pluralize(@tuto.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this tuto from being saved:"
      ul
        - @tuto.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          li = message
  = f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id
  = f.input  :title
  = f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Choose a category"}
  = f.input :content, as: :text, input_html: { rows: "15" }
  = f.button :submit, "Save"
```

the tutos_controller.rb

```
class TutosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_tuto, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote]


  def index
    @tutos = Tuto.all.includes(:user, :category)
  end

  def show
    @tuto = Tuto.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.all
  end


  def new
    @tuto = Tuto.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create

    @tuto = Tuto.new(tuto_params)
    @tuto.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @tuto.save
        flash[:success] = "Test"
        format.html { redirect_to @tuto, notice: 'Tuto was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @tuto }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @tuto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @tuto.update(tuto_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @tuto, notice: 'Tuto was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @tuto }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @tuto.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @tuto.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tutos_url, notice: 'Tuto was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end


  def upvote
    @tuto.upvote_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private
    # def get_user
    #   @user = User.find(@tuto.user_id)
    # end

    def set_tuto
      @tuto = Tuto.find(params[:id])
    end

    def tuto_params
      params.require(:tuto).permit(:title, :content, :id, :user_id, :category_id)
    end
end
```

the categories_controller.rb

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

  private

    def categories_params
      params.require(:categories).permit(:name, :description, :id)
    end

end
```

my views/tutos/index.html.slim

```
.container
  .row
    .col-xs-12.col-sm-12
      h1.text-gray Tutorials 
      br
      -if user_signed_in?
        = link_to "Create a tuto", new_tuto_path, class:"btn btn-success"
  
  #tutos.transitions-enabled
    - @tutos.each do |tuto|
      .box.panel-default
        -if tuto.category.name == "Ruby"
          =image_tag("select/ruby.png")
        -elsif tuto.category.name == "Rails 4"
          =image_tag("selec/rails4.png")
        -elsif tuto.category.name == "Rails 5"
          =image_tag("selec/rails5.png")
        -elsif tuto.category.name == "Heroku"
          =image_tag("select/heroku.png")
        -elsif tuto.category.name == "AWS"
          =image_tag("select/aws.png")
    
        
          
        = link_to tuto.title, tuto_path(tuto)      
        h6 Created by:
        = tuto.user.full_name
    hr
```

my schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160920133801) do

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "image"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "tutos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "category_id"
  end

  add_index "tutos", ["user_id"], name: "index_tutos_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.boolean  "admin"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

  create_table "votes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "votable_id"
    t.string   "votable_type"
    t.integer  "voter_id"
    t.string   "voter_type"
    t.boolean  "vote_flag"
    t.string   "vote_scope"
    t.integer  "vote_weight"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "votes", ["votable_id", "votable_type", "vote_scope"], name: "index_votes_on_votable_id_and_votable_type_and_vote_scope"
  add_index "votes", ["voter_id", "voter_type", "vote_scope"], name: "index_votes_on_voter_id_and_voter_type_and_vote_scope"

end
```

EDIT here is the error message:
[image]

Comment: What route or action gives you the error? Does it give you a line number?

Comment: please see my edit, :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you may have created at least one Tuto object without a category_id at some point and it's still in your (development?) database. I'm guessing you don't want that, in which case I usually wipe my development database with `rake db:reset`. Just make sure you're executing commands in development if you do that of course. In the future, you may want to validate the presence of category_id on your Tuto model as well.